# How to configure TCP_KEEPALIVE under MAC OS X

Tags: c++, c, macos

Currently I've encountered this problem: how to detect unpredictable connection broken.

I utilized SO_KEEPALIVE,TCP_KEEPIDLE,TCP_KEEPINTVL and TCP_KEEPCNT to solve it under linux, which seems working fine now.

However,  It really took me a long time to find out how to work it out under MAC OS X. Somebody suggested me to turn to netinet/tcp_var.h, but still none of the aforementioned MACRO was found.

So, my question is,

How to implementation TCP KEEPALIVE under MAC OS X?

P.S.: my MAC OS X version is 10.8.3,and my gcc/g++ version is 4.2.1

Any reply would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, Darwin (BSD) is simpler than Linux. Set the TCP_KEEPALIVE (secs) option, as well as the SO_KEEPALIVE (bool) option:

```
int on = 1, secs = 10;
setsockopt(skt, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_KEEPALIVE, &on, sizeof on);
setsockopt(skt, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPALIVE, &secs, sizeof secs);
```

To see what the default interval is (if you just did the SO_KEEPALIVE), use:

```
sysctl -A | grep net.inet.tcp.*keep
```

You'll probably see:

```
net.inet.tcp.keepidle: 7200000
net.inet.tcp.keepintvl: 75000
net.inet.tcp.keepinit: 75000
net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive: 0
```

i.e. keepalive is only on for sockets with SO_KEEPALIVE set, and the idle timeout is 72000.000 msecs (2 hours). HTH.

Comment: That should be `sysctl`, not `netstat`.

Comment: But how do you change those values? I need to shorten them as well but I'm not seeing HOW?

Comment: As mentioned by user "nos" below, those parameters can only be set by someone with privilege to run sysctl on that ... they are indeed system-wide settings.
Yes, I know might suck :-).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `setsockopt()`, see it's man page

It looks like the `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, `TCP_KEEPINTVL` and `TCP_KEEPCNT` are Linux specific and you won't find their equivalent counter parts on OSX.

To set the `SO_KEEPALIVE` do this

```
int optval = 1;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, &optval, sizeof(optval));
```

Another trick I used long time ago was to try to send 0 (zero) number of bytes, this would check that a socket is still alive. Either as a repetitive *watch dog* or just before trying to send a message.

Comment: of course it should be setsockopt(), the problem is "how". I cannot find any of the above option, namely "TCP_KEEPIDLE","TCP_KEEPINTVL", "TCP_KEEPALIVE" and "TCP_KEEPCNT"

Comment: I thought the question was about `SO_KEEPALIVE`, which I see is present for `setsockopt()`.

Comment: But, by default, the time interval of TCP KEEPALIVE is 2 hours which is definitely unbearable. The KEY POINT of my question is how to configure these under MAC OS X. I got no problem with these under linux.

Comment: @House.Lee Some of those are system wide parameters on OSX as mentioned in the answer of Mischa (Set with e.g. the sysctl command)